# How to parse a .yml file without %YAML:1.0 header [C++]

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

I need to parse a .yml file which doesn't have a header, which on the other hand is required by OpenCV.
How OpenCV wants a .yml file to look like:

```
%YAML:1.0
---
data:
    - coordinates: [....]
    filename: "..."
    - coordinates: [....]
    filename: "..."
```

How our files look like:

```
data:
    - coordinates: [....]
    filename: "..."
    - coordinates: [....]
    filename: "..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update - I prepared a ready to use function to read OpenCV Yaml without **%YAML:1.0** header

```
cv::FileStorage readFileStorage(const std::filesystem::path path)
{
    std::ifstream file(path, std::iostream::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!file.good())
    {
        return "";
    }

    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::eofbit);

    auto length(file.tellg());
    std::string buffer(length, '\0');

    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(&buffer[0], length);
    if(buffer.empty())
    {
         return cv::FileStorage();
    }
    cv::String dataString = "%YAML:1.0\n" + buffer;
    return cv::FileStorage(dataString, cv::FileStorage::READ | cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
}
```

What I did was pushing the header into the filestream just before it reads it:

```
std::vector<char> buffer;
// make buffer read the file
buffer.push_back(0) // add 0 so OpenCV can treat this buffer as char* string
cv::String dataString = "%YAML:1.0\n" + cv::String(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
cv::FileStorage fs(dataString, cv::FileStorage::READ | cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
```

Having this, I was able to parse .yml file without a header

```
fs["data"] >> data;
```